# Passing data from front end to route in backend React

Tags: reactjs, express

I am currently new to using React and express, I wish to send data which i have received from a form. The data i would like to send back is the UserInfo or email which is in the state. However I am extremely unsure how I am supposed to go about this request.

```
class ForgotPassword extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

    this.state = { 
        email:'',
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}

    componentDidMount = () =>{
        // this.fetchUserInfo();
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState ({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const userInfo = { 
            email : this.state.email 

        };  



            fetch("/forgotpassword", {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify(userInfo),
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })
              .then(response => {
                return response.json();
              })
              .then(jsonData => {
                console.log(jsonData);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error with data fetch " + err);
              });
          };

This is my form...


<div className='row'>
                    <div className='col'></div>
                    <div className='col card form'>
                    <h1 id="title">Reset Password</h1>
                    <h5 id="passinstruc">Please enter your email to reset your password</h5>
                        <form id="forgotpass" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email </label>
                                <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" className="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" value={this.state.email} />
                                <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            </div>

                            <button id="loginbtn" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Submit</button>
                            <br/>
                            <div className='division'>
                                <Link  to="/register" className='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'  id="registerbtn" >  Create your account here</Link>
                            </div>


                        </form>
                    </div>
```

In my backend I am getting a POST /forgotpassword 404 message but I dont know why. Help would be much appreciated.

This is my backend route where I will be sending the information

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require ('../connection');
var email = require ('./sendEmail');



router.post('/forgotpassword', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.email);

    var userEmail = req.email;

    var text = "Follow the instructions below to reset your password"

    email.sendEmailWithTemplate(userEmail,'PetS.o.S Password Reset', text);
});
```

Comment: I think you need to write complete URL in fetch like `"http://localhost:3000/forgotpassword"` considering you are using on local and express is also running on local.

Answer (score 0):

For sending data you will need the domain name or ip address of your server.

Once you obtained that, you can use jQuery.get - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

or jQuery.post -
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Or if you are not using jQuery, use XMLHttpRequest -
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending data in body send it in response.

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/

  fetch('/api/getList')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(list => this.setState({ list }))
- https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3